# Change focus to next component in JTable using TAB

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, focusmanager

JTable's default behavior is changing focus to next cell and I want to force it to move focus to next component (e.g. JTextField) on TAB key pressed.
I overrided `isCellEditable` method of `DefaultTableModel` to always return false:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
}
```

But it still doesn't change focus to next component!
How should I make `JTable` change focus to next component instead of next cell?

Comment: are we talking about Focus 1) inside JTable betweens cells 2) moving focus from JTable to (for example) JTextField and vice versa

Comment: @mKorbel: #2 , JTable's default behavior is changing focus to next cell and I want to force it to move focus to next component (e.g. `JTextField`) on TAB key pressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want this, you need to change the default behavior of the tables action map.

```
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
am.put("selectPreviousColumnCell", new PreviousFocusHandler());    
am.put("selectNextColumnCell", new NextFocusHandler());
```

Then you need a couple of actions to handle the traversal

```
public class PreviousFocusHandler extends AbstractAction {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.focusPreviousComponent();
    }
}

public class NextFocusHandler extends AbstractAction {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.focusNextComponent();
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to disable the underlying `Action`...

```
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
am.get("selectPreviousColumnCell").setEnabled(false);
am.get("selectNextColumnCell").setEnabled(false);
```

(haven't tested this)

The benefit of this approach is can enable/disable the behaviour as you need it without needing to maintain a reference to the old `Actions`

Comment: ? KeyboardFocusManager ? Was going to mention Componet.transferFocusXXX(), but had 4 month of to burp :P

Answer (score 15):

The shift-/tab keys are used by default for transfering focus between components. JTable explicitly requests to handle the shift-/tab internally (by providing sets of focusTraversalKeys which doesn't include those).

Following the general rule (*if there's specilized api available for a task, use that instead of rolling your own*), the solution is to set traversal keys to again contain them:

```
Set<AWTKeyStroke> forward = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>(
        table.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
forward.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB"));
table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, forward);
Set<AWTKeyStroke> backward = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>(
        table.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS));
backward.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB"));
table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, backward);
```

Answer (score 5):

- default (implemented `KeyBinding` for `JTable`) is about next cell and from last cell to first,
- you can to [remove KeyBindings by setting to the null value](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Answer (score 4):

To reset to the standard keyboard bindings (typically TAB and SHIFT+TAB), simply specify `null` for the `keystrokes` parameter to `Component.setFocusTraversalKeys`:

```
table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
table.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
```