# tab key can't transfer focus for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus

So i have 2 components in my frame, a table and a text field. but when
the table has the focus and I hit tab key, the focus doesn't go to the text
field. Why this is happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            String[][] data = { { "Data" } };
            String[] cols = { "COlo" };
            JTable table = new JTable(data, cols);
            table.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

                public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("focus lost");
                }

                public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("gained");
                }
            });
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            table.requestFocus();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an old article, but it might provide an explanation for what you are seeing.  https://www.java.net/node/651087.  Also, try searching StackOverflow for "JTable focustraversalpolicy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Because the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is used for cell-to-cell navigation in a `JTable`, the [*Focus Subsystem*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) uses <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate *out* of the `JTable`. See [*Customizing Focus Traversal*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal) for an example. You can alter the default behavior as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155027/230513).